# Post multiple check box value using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

i currently facing a problem to post my checkbox value to my php to update the query. I'm currently using ajax to post it, but it seem like it posting the empty data to the GET function on my php side.

Is there anything i had to add on in order to post my checkbox value ? Please point it out. Thanks

Here is my ajax code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                //File and text upload with formDATA function
                $("form#form").submit(function(){
                var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);    
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'masterItem.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        async: false,
                        beforeSend: function(){
                         if(confirm('Are you sure to change the kiosks mode?'))
                              return true;
                          else
                              return false;
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    }).done(function () {
                            //do something if you want when the post is successfully
                            if(!alert('Form Had Successfully Inserted.')){document.getelementbyclassname('form').reset()}
                    }).fail(function () {
                            //if the post is failed show an error message if you want
                            alert('Some error occur. Please try again later.');
                    });
                    return false;

            });

            }); 
        </script>
```

Sample of my checkbox code:

```
<form action="" id="form" class="form">
                        <div class="anchor">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="All Master" data-name="All Master" id="myCheckBox0" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> All Kedai Kiosk On Master Mode</label>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Selangor" data-name="Selangor"  id="myCheckBox1" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Selangor</label>
                                            <ul id="navlist">
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="1" data-id="Kiosk 1" data-name="Kiosk 1" id="myCheckBox2" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 1&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="2" data-id="Kiosk 2" data-name="Kiosk 2" id="myCheckBox3" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 2&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li> 
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="5" data-id="Kiosk 5" data-name="Kiosk 5" id="myCheckBox4" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 5&nbsp;</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="7" data-id="Kiosk 7" data-name="Kiosk 7" id="myCheckBox5" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 7&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="8" data-id="Kiosk 8" data-name="Kiosk 8" id="myCheckBox6" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 8&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li> 
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="9" data-id="Kiosk 9" data-name="Kiosk 9" id="myCheckBox7" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 9&nbsp;</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="10" data-id="Kiosk 10" data-name="Kiosk 10" id="myCheckBox8" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 10</label></li>   
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="11" data-id="Kiosk 11" data-name="Kiosk 11" id="myCheckBox9" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 11</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="12" data-id="Kiosk 12" data-name="Kiosk 12" id="myCheckBox10" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 12</label></li>  
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="13" data-id="Kiosk 13" data-name="Kiosk 13" id="myCheckBox11" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 13</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="14" data-id="Kiosk 14" data-name="Kiosk 14" id="myCheckBox12" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 14</label></li>  
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="15" data-id="Kiosk 15" data-name="Kiosk 15" id="myCheckBox13" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 15</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="16" data-id="Kiosk 16" data-name="Kiosk 16" id="myCheckBox14" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 16</label></li>  
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="17" data-id="Kiosk 17" data-name="Kiosk 17" id="myCheckBox15" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 17</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="18" data-id="Kiosk 18" data-name="Kiosk 18" id="myCheckBox16" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 18</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="19" data-id="Kiosk 19" data-name="Kiosk 19" id="myCheckBox17" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 19</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="20" data-id="Kiosk 20" data-name="Kiosk 20" id="myCheckBox18" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 20</label></li>  
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="21" data-id="Kiosk 21" data-name="Kiosk 21" id="myCheckBox19" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 21</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="22" data-id="Kiosk 22" data-name="Kiosk 22" id="myCheckBox20" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 22</label></li>  
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="23" data-id="Kiosk 23" data-name="Kiosk 23" id="myCheckBox21" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 23</label></li>  
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <li>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Putrajaya" data-name="Putrajaya" id="myCheckBox22" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Putrajaya</label>
                                            <ul id="navlist">
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="23" data-id="Kiosk 24" data-name="Kiosk 24" id="myCheckBox23" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 24</label></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <li>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Kuala Lumpur" data-name="Kuala Lumpur" id="myCheckBox24" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kuala Lumpur</label>
                                            <ul id="navlist">
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="25" data-id="Kiosk 26" data-name="Kiosk 26" id="myCheckBox25" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 26</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="26" data-id="Kiosk 27" data-name="Kiosk 27" id="myCheckBox26" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 27</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="27" data-id="Kiosk 28" data-name="Kiosk 28" id="myCheckBox27" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 28</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="28" data-id="Kiosk 29" data-name="Kiosk 29" id="myCheckBox28" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 29</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="29" data-id="Kiosk 30" data-name="Kiosk 30" id="myCheckBox29" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 30</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="30" data-id="Kiosk 31" data-name="Kiosk 31" id="myCheckBox30" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 31</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="31" data-id="Kiosk 32" data-name="Kiosk 32" id="myCheckBox31" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 32</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="32" data-id="Kiosk 33" data-name="Kiosk 33" id="myCheckBox32" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" /> Kiosk 33</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="33" data-id="Kiosk 34" data-name="Kiosk 34" id="myCheckBox33" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 34</label></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <li>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Pahang" data-name="Pahang" id="myCheckBox34" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Pahang</label>
                                            <ul id="navlist">
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="35" data-id="Kiosk 35" data-name="Kiosk 35" id="myCheckBox35" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 35</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="36" data-id="Kiosk 36" data-name="Kiosk 36" id="myCheckBox36" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 36</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="37" data-id="Kiosk 37" data-name="Kiosk 37" id="myCheckBox37" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 37</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="6" data-id="Kiosk 6" data-name="Kiosk 6" id="myCheckBox38" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 6</label></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <li>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Perak" data-name="Perak" id="myCheckBox39" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Perak</label>
                                            <ul id="navlist">
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="38" data-id="Kiosk 38" data-name="Kiosk 38" id="myCheckBox40" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 38</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="39" data-id="Kiosk 39" data-name="Kiosk 39" id="myCheckBox41" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 39</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="40" data-id="Kiosk 40" data-name="Kiosk 40" id="myCheckBox42" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 40</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="41" data-id="Kiosk 41" data-name="Kiosk 41" id="myCheckBox43" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 41</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="42" data-id="Kiosk 42" data-name="Kiosk 42" id="myCheckBox44" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 42</label></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <li>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Kedah" data-name="Kedah" id="myCheckBox45" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kedah</label>
                                            <ul id="navlist">
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="43" data-id="Kiosk 43" data-name="Kiosk 43" id="myCheckBox46" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 43</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="44" data-id="Kiosk 44" data-name="Kiosk 44" id="myCheckBox47" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 44</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="45" data-id="Kiosk 45" data-name="Kiosk 45" id="myCheckBox48" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 45</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="46" data-id="Kiosk 46" data-name="Kiosk 46" id="myCheckBox49" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 46</label></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <li>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Pulau Pinang" data-name="Pulau Pinang" id="myCheckBox50" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Pulau Pinang</label>
                                            <ul id="navlist">
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="47" data-id="Kiosk 47" data-name="Kiosk 47" id="myCheckBox51" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 47</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="48" data-id="Kiosk 48" data-name="Kiosk 48" id="myCheckBox52" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 48</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="49" data-id="Kiosk 49" data-name="Kiosk 49" id="myCheckBox53" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 49</label></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <li>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Melaka" data-name="Melaka" id="myCheckBox54" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Melaka</label>
                                            <ul id="navlist">
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="50" data-id="Kiosk 50" data-name="Kiosk 50" id="myCheckBox55" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 50</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="51" data-id="Kiosk 51" data-name="Kiosk 51" id="myCheckBox56" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 51</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="25" data-id="Kiosk 25" data-name="Kiosk 25" id="myCheckBox57" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 25</label></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <li>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Perlis" data-name="Perlis" id="myCheckBox58" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Perlis</label>
                                            <ul id="navlist">
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="52" data-id="Kiosk 52" data-name="Kiosk 52" id="myCheckBox59" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 52</label></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <li>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Negeri Sembilan" data-name="Negeri Sembilan" id="myCheckBox60" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Negeri Sembilan</label>
                                            <ul id="navlist">
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="53" data-id="Kiosk 53" data-name="Kiosk 53" id="myCheckBox61" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 53</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="54" data-id="Kiosk 54" data-name="Kiosk 54" id="myCheckBox62" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 54</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="65" data-id="Kiosk 65" data-name="Kiosk 65" id="myCheckBox63" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 65</label></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <li>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Johor" data-name="Johor" id="myCheckBox64" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Johor</label>
                                            <ul id="navlist">
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="55" data-id="Kiosk 55" data-name="Kiosk 55" id="myCheckBox65" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 55</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="56" data-id="Kiosk 56" data-name="Kiosk 56" id="myCheckBox66" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 56</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="57" data-id="Kiosk 57" data-name="Kiosk 57" id="myCheckBox67" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 57</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="58" data-id="Kiosk 58" data-name="Kiosk 58" id="myCheckBox68" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 58</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="59" data-id="Kiosk 59" data-name="Kiosk 59" id="myCheckBox69" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 59</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="60" data-id="Kiosk 60" data-name="Kiosk 60" id="myCheckBox70" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 60</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="3" data-id="Kiosk 3" data-name="Kiosk 3" id="myCheckBox71" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 3</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="4" data-id="Kiosk 4" data-name="Kiosk 4" id="myCheckBox72" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 4</label></li>
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="61" data-id="Kiosk 61" data-name="Kiosk 61" id="myCheckBox73" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 61</label></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <li>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Kelantan" data-name="Kelantan" id="myCheckBox74" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kelantan</label>
                                            <ul id="navlist">
                                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="62" data-id="Kiosk 62" data-name="Kiosk 62" id="myCheckBox75" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 62</label></li>
                                            </ul>


        </li>
                                    <hr/>
                                    <li>
                                        <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Terengganu" data-name="Terengganu" id="myCheckBox76" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Terengganu</label>
                                        <ul id="navlist">
                                            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="63" data-id="Kiosk 63" data-name="Kiosk 63" id="myCheckBox77" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 63</label></li>
                                            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="64" data-id="Kiosk 64" data-name="Kiosk 64" id="myCheckBox78" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 64</label></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Selected items (readable): <span class="selected-readable"></span></p>
                        <p>Selected items: <span class="selected">[]</span></p>
                        <p>Excepted items: <span class="excepted">[]</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <button id="testing" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Submit </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Nothing looks wrong at first glance. What does it say you're sending in Developer Tools?

Comment: Twenty-three times `onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"` looks wrong, but not for the current problem :)

Comment: i get this error message on the developer tools

Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery.min.js:1:0
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:5:0
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/